# Unable to execute system command from sqlalchemy as in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Execution of system command using sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection is resulting in error.

```
import sqlalchemy
from urllib.parse import quote_plus as urlquote
user = 'root'
host = 'localhost'
port = 3306
password = 'mypassword'
engine_string = 'mysql://{0}:%s@{1}:{2}/{3}'.format(user, host, port, db_name) % urlquote(password)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_string)
db = engine.connect()

db.execute(r"\! sh /home/satish/test.sh")
```

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\! sh /home/satish/test.sh' at line 1")
[SQL: ! sh /home/satish/test.sh]

Comment: I have some ordered mysql queries like query1;system cmd1;query2;query3
It works fine in mysql terminal and not in sqlalchemy as it is escaping \ with another \.

Comment: The MySQL client app has some [builtin commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html). These are preprocessed by the MySQL client app itself, so none of these commands can be executed when you use one of the MySQL programmatic APIs.